# Show a custom message if the total price for a product goes over a certain value

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I am new to Magento and now trying to find a way to show a message on a product page (preferably instead of the "Add to Cart" button), if the total price (based on several custom options) for a product goes over a certain limit, but I can't figure out a way to do so. I have tried searching for the variable responsible for the total price, to create a php "if" expression, but so far I have no luck. Is there a way to make this message appear? Or maybe someone could give me a hint where to look for the total price variable?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$_product->getFinalPrice()
```

It will retrieve the product's price you can include in your `if` condition.